# Docker cannot run on Centos VM

Tags: docker, centos

There is an error cannot start docker after did `yum update` on Centos with error message :

```
error response from daemon : failed to initialize logging driver: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
For verbose messaging see.aws.config.CredentialsChainVerboseError.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by add credentials variable AWS Key on path :
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX"
Environment="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX"
Environment="AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=XXX"
```